# ProgressBar not indicating set value

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a button that ultimately opens a new window displaying several buttons.
While this window is loading and the criteria for loading it are being determined, I would like to display a progress bar.

```
  private void Select_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loading_Window progress = new Loading_Window(20);
        progress.Show();
        //BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        //worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        //worker.DoWork += DoWork;
        //worker.ProgressChanged += progressChanged;
        //worker.RunWorkerCompleted += workerCompleted;
        //worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        try
        {
            if (Requests_listbox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                if (Requests_listbox.SelectedItems.Count > 3)
                {
                    Popup Error = new Popup("message");
                    Error.ShowDialog();
                    Requests_listbox.SelectedItems.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    progress.Update_Progress(40);
                    foreach (Class1 jargon in Requests_listbox.SelectedItems)
                    {
                        Selection.Add(jargon);
                    }
                    progress.Update_Progress(80);
                    new_window my_new_window = new new_window(Selection, Requests_listbox.SelectedItems.Count) { Owner = this };

                    my_new_Window.ShowDialog();
                    FillChart();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Popup Error = new Popup("message");
                Error.Show();
                FillChart();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```

and my Loading_Window class is as follows:

```
    public partial class Loading_Window : Window
{
    public Loading_Window(int _progress)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loading_progress.Value = _progress;
    }

    public void Update_Progress(int updated_progress)
    {
        Loading_progress.Value = updated_progress;
        Loading_progress.UpdateLayout();

    }
}
```

I tried using a background worker various times, but I was unable to implement it successfully... I don't know if I'm missing something simple, or what the case is.

Any advice would be appreciated..

EDIT:

I've added the following button to simplify things, but I'm having trouble implementing INotifyPropertyChanged...

```
private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //"Log Out" button
    {
        Loading_Window test = new Loading_Window(0);
        test.Show();
        test.updated_progress = 10;
        test.updated_progress = 20;
        test.updated_progress = 30;
        test.updated_progress = 40;
        test.updated_progress = 50;
        test.updated_progress = 60;
        test.updated_progress = 70;
        test.updated_progress = 80;
        test.updated_progress = 90;
        test.updated_progress = 100;
        test.Close();
    }


public partial class Loading_Window : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Loading_Window(double _progress)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loading_progress.Value = _progress;
    }

    public double updated_progress
    {
        get
        {
            return Loading_progress.Value;
        }

        set
        {
            Loading_progress.Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("updated_progress");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property_name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property_name));
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
<Window x:Class="jawn.Loading_Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStyle="None" Background="Black"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="Loading_Window" Height="200" Width="600">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Please wait...Operation in progress..." FontSize="25" Foreground="Wheat"/>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="Loading_progress" Value="{Binding updated_progress}" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="572"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the specific problem that you're having with this?  I wouldn't recommend trying to do anything on a background thread here because you would be accessing UI elements from a different thread, which is not only a bad practice, but also dangerous (if even allowed without throwing an exception).

While I would prefer to do something like this via MVVM and to overlay a progress indicator over the same window (or place a dark translucent layer over the existing controls for a fancier approach), I think the quickest way to do what you want given the code you've provided is:

```
Loading_Window progress = new Loading_Window(20);
try
{
    progress.Show();
    if (Requests_listbox.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if (Requests_listbox.SelectedItems.Count > 3)
        {
            progress.Close();

            Popup Error = new Popup("message");
            Error.ShowDialog();
            Requests_listbox.SelectedItems.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            progress.Update_Progress(40);
            foreach (Class1 jargon in Requests_listbox.SelectedItems)
            {
                Selection.Add(Selected_item);
            }
            progress.Update_Progress(80);
            new_window my_new_window = new new_window(Selection, Requests_listbox.SelectedItems.Count) { Owner = this };

            progress.Close();

            my_new_Window.ShowDialog();
            FillChart();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        progress.Close();

        Popup Error = new Popup("message");
        Error.Show();
        FillChart();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
```

I'm guessing that your main problem is that you're progress bar isn't disappearing when you want it to, which would be the expected behavior since I don't see any code to close it, and you have to close it before a blocking modal dialog call to ShowDialog().

EDIT:

Your main problem is that you're binding the Value of the progress bar in XAML, and also trying to set it in code, which will fail.  Since you're not binding to a ViewModel/DataContext, don't set any binding in XAML and instead leave your code as it was to directly set the Value of the control.

A secondary problem that you might be having is that you could be modifying values on the ProgressBar before the window is actually shown, which isn't necessarily a bad thing but could result in the window being shown with non-zero initial value.  You could do something like:

```
Loading_Window test = new Loading_Window(0);
test.Loaded += delegate
{
    // Perform progress status update logic here
}
```

Comment: I hadn't even realized I wasn't closing the progress bar...silly me.

My bigger problem is, however, when updating the value of the progress bar, the value is not being reflected in the progress bar itself.

I thought the Loading_progress.UpdateLayout() call within the Loading_Window class would take care of this...

Comment: What type is Loading_progress?  If it's your own type that a control is bound to, check if it's implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and correctly firing the notification.

Comment: I've added my edits so far up above...my attempts to implement INotifyPropertyChanged...still having no luck...when OnPropertyChanged is called handler never becomes != null

Comment: Updated my answer based on the additional info

Comment: I still cannot get this to work.  I've deleted the binding from my .xaml.  My event handler is still never happening...When I add a MessageBox.Show() after each test.updated_progress call the progress bar updates...but if I remove the messageboxes the bar just cranks through and never updates.

Comment: This is correct behavior.  MessageBox is model, so you'd have to create your own form that mimics a message box and call Show() on that instead, or just display the error on the progress dialog itself.